# Baker's Angel Flake Coconut

Tags: baking, measurements

I have an old recipe that calls for a large can of Baker's Angel Flake Coconut.
How many ounces were these cans; I need to substitute the bags that are available now.

Answer (score 2):

A similar can 7 inches(17.78cm) high and 3 inches(7.62cm) dia had a labed tare weight of 7 ounces(198.45g)

https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pre-1963-Vintage-Bakers-Angel-Flake-Coconut-Tin-Can-Advertising-5-1-2-Height-/153154542442?_trksid=p2385738.m4383.l4275.c10